# Jquery datatable row re-ordering doesn't work after sorting column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am facing issue in which **row reordering** stops working after sorting any of the column.The row comes back to same position from where it is picked for drop.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: please show your code here?what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use dataTable 1.10.x and the "native" [RowReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) plugin. add the following files to your project :

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

$('#table').DataTable({
rowReorder: true
});

Check demo : https://jsfiddle.net/u7mdqwot/
```

Comment: below fiddle use ur suggestions ,but you can see that it doesnt work when sorting applied :(
http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/

Comment: plz check with new demo link

Comment: where is it :)  ?

Comment: same again.try to sort by Name and then then re-order the row,it wint work.

Comment: i have check with sort by name and reorder it works with both browsers(FF and Chrome). Plz check https://jsfiddle.net/u7mdqwot/

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.
It seems that sorting and row reordering doesn't work parallel.

```
gtblAssignedTasks = $("#tblAssignedTasks").DataTable({
"language": {                        
"oPaginate": {
"sFirst": "<<",
"sPrevious": "<", 
"sNext": ">" ,
"sLast": ">>"
},
"emptyTable":"No record found"   
},
"dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt',
'iDisplayLength': 50,                
"bLengthChange": true,                  
"responsive": false,
"bFilter": true,                    
'rowReorder': {
dataSrc: 'Priority' 
},  
columnDefs:  [
{ targets:0, visible: false }
] ,

"bSort": true,
"bauto":false,
"bPaginate": true,
"Paging": true,
"bInfo":false,
//Commented,as Pager and filter isnt required
"sDom": '<"row tblAssignedTasks"   <"col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-right filter"Rr>  ><"" t><"row zeromargin clsFooter" <"span9"p> >',
"pagingType": "full_numbers",
"sServerMethod": "POST",                                                         
"sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetToDoListTasks", "Test")",
"aoColumns":tblAssignedTasksColumns,
"createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) 
{




},
"initComplete": function() 
{



}
});//datatable end
```

by setting "bSort": false   even didnt work.
So my workaround was to set "bSort": true in datatable initialization and set individual column's sorting to false in column definitions as below

```
    var tblAssignedTasksColumns= [

                     { "sTitle": "Priority", "mData": "Priority" , "sClass": "reorder", "sDefaultContent": ""   }   ,
                     { "sTitle": "Priority", "mData": "Priority1" ,"sClass": "reorder"   ,  'bSortable': false, "mRender": function (data, type, row)
                     { 
                     return GetPriorityRandom(row)  ;}, "sDefaultContent": "1"  },   
                     { "sTitle": "Description", "mData": "KindOfAlert",  'bSortable': false, "sClass": "tblDest ", "sDefaultContent": "","mRender": function (data, type, row){
                      return GeneratePriorityLabel(row )
                    } 
                    } 
                    , { "sTitle": "Status", "mData": "Status",  'bSortable': false, "sClass": "clstblInvoiceAdjustment tdAssignedTasksStatus", "mRender": function (data, type, row)
                      { return GetStatus(row) }, "sDefaultContent": ""  }

                ];
```